# Why rclcpp_action create_client cannot choose qos options?

Tags: ros, ros2, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I'm trying to understand the actionlib of ROS2. I have a question as title... (Hope this question not too stupid)

In [rclcpp_action create_action](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/0dd14baa32718b2958c57b02e92a31fc441bdb30/rclcpp_action/include/rclcpp_action/create_server.hpp#L133), user can choose which qos they want but why in rclcpp_action create_client doesn't have this function?

Please kindly help me. Many thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352385/why-rclcpp_action-create_client-cannot-choose-qos-options?/) by [PowerfulMing](https://answers.ros.org/users/40080/powerfulming/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2020-05-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-05-14**:
I don't think that's a stupid question, from a 3 minute glance to try to answer your question, I couldn't find a good answer to that either.

**Comment by [PowerfulMing](https://answers.ros.org/users/40080/powerfulming/) on 2020-05-17**:
Thank you! I just afraid that I didn't read ROS2 Documents carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The action server and action client implementations were contributed independently, so I think this is just something that was overlooked. Feel free to open up an issue (or even better, a pull request) for adding the API.

Note, because it will involve changing API, it will have to target a release after Foxy.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PowerfulMing](https://answers.ros.org/users/40080/powerfulming/) on 2020-05-17**:
Thanks for your reply. I'll try to open an issue first. :)